# How do I find the password that Xubuntu asks me to enter when I seek to update software?

Tags: password

How do I find the password that Xubuntu asks me to enter when I seek to update software? I have been attempting to update my software in order to enable Universe (or at least having a first bash at this), but I'm required to enter a password. So far as I'm aware I have not been given such a password. Where would I find it?

Answer (score 3):

It's asking for your login password.

Answer (score 0):

> So far as I'm aware I have not been given such a password.

It is the one you have to insert when installing the system. That user is the admin of the system and is the one that can install by default.

All other users the same applies but those users need to be made admin by the current admin to be able to install or that admin can also enable the ability to install for a user.

> Where would I find it?

You can ONLY reset your password. Passwords are protected with an encryption tool. See [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) on how to reset your admin password.